# HTTPS problems with cookies C#

Tags: c#

OK, now that I have investigated the code, there are no cookies to speak of when it comes to storing the cookie collection in a `CookieContainer`, so I would like to divert and use the headers. The only problem is I do not understand how to use them so that I may download the file form the website.

Could someone give me an example of how I would potentially use headers?

Also the code I used for the cookies is as follows, maybe there is a mistake:

```
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        CookieContainer newCookies = new CookieContainer();
        newCookies.Add(response.Cookies);
```

All I get is this header `Headers = {Content-Length: 6292
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 22 Jul 2012 03:12:59 GMT
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=dpub2i550ynjfonuv0o0n4nb; domain=website.co.nz; path=/; HttpOnly
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-AspNet-Vers...`

The code does not throw an exception. Just as a side not I am using `request.Method = "GET";`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the result of the `.ToString()` method which is called when viewing the variable in the debugger. You need to access the members of `CookieContainer`.

Comment: I feel stupid right now for asking, but could you elaborate on where the `.ToString()` would be placed? at the end of the 'response.Cookies'? or at the end of the `.GetResponse()`. I wager on the `.GetResponse()` but I am unsure, I will give it a go and let you know. Thanks!